# LiteIDE for GO: cannot run delve

Tags: liteide

I'm running on OSX 10.12.2 the LiteIDE X30.3, XCode 8.2. I just installed delve and re-run LiteIDE, when I try to run the debugger I get the following output in the LiteIDE console:

```
02:02:45 LiteApp: Initializing
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded MIME folderproject.xml
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded MIME gopackage.xml
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded MIME liteeditor.xml
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded MIME qsqleditor.xml
02:02:45 WordApiManager: Loading /private/var/folders/8n/b15fh_dj3ps6xm3lb0vh2ps00000gq/T/AppTranslocation/66A1867F-FF2B-438C-88EC-60DB52BA70A8/d/LiteIDE.app/Contents/Resources/packages
02:02:45 load word api: /private/var/folders/8n/b15fh_dj3ps6xm3lb0vh2ps00000gq/T/AppTranslocation/66A1867F-FF2B-438C-88EC-60DB52BA70A8/d/LiteIDE.app/Contents/Resources/packages/go/funcs.api,/private/var/folders/8n/b15fh_dj3ps6xm3lb0vh2ps00000gq/T/AppTranslocation/66A1867F-FF2B-438C-88EC-60DB52BA70A8/d/LiteIDE.app/Contents/Resources/packages/go/keyword.api,/private/var/folders/8n/b15fh_dj3ps6xm3lb0vh2ps00000gq/T/AppTranslocation/66A1867F-FF2B-438C-88EC-60DB52BA70A8/d/LiteIDE.app/Contents/Resources/packages/go/types.api
02:02:45 load snippet api: /private/var/folders/8n/b15fh_dj3ps6xm3lb0vh2ps00000gq/T/AppTranslocation/66A1867F-FF2B-438C-88EC-60DB52BA70A8/d/LiteIDE.app/Contents/Resources/packages/go/go.snippet.json
02:02:45 load word api: /private/var/folders/8n/b15fh_dj3ps6xm3lb0vh2ps00000gq/T/AppTranslocation/66A1867F-FF2B-438C-88EC-60DB52BA70A8/d/LiteIDE.app/Contents/Resources/packages/lua/luabase.api,/private/var/folders/8n/b15fh_dj3ps6xm3lb0vh2ps00000gq/T/AppTranslocation/66A1867F-FF2B-438C-88EC-60DB52BA70A8/d/LiteIDE.app/Contents/Resources/packages/lua/lualib.api,/private/var/folders/8n/b15fh_dj3ps6xm3lb0vh2ps00000gq/T/AppTranslocation/66A1867F-FF2B-438C-88EC-60DB52BA70A8/d/LiteIDE.app/Contents/Resources/packages/lua/lualib5_annot.api
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/liteeditor
02:02:45 LiteEnv: Loaded environment files from /private/var/folders/8n/b15fh_dj3ps6xm3lb0vh2ps00000gq/T/AppTranslocation/66A1867F-FF2B-438C-88EC-60DB52BA70A8/d/LiteIDE.app/Contents/Resources/liteenv
02:02:45 LiteEnv: load environment darwin64-local
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/liteenv
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/quickopen
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/litefind
02:02:45 BuildManager: Loading /private/var/folders/8n/b15fh_dj3ps6xm3lb0vh2ps00000gq/T/AppTranslocation/66A1867F-FF2B-438C-88EC-60DB52BA70A8/d/LiteIDE.app/Contents/Resources/litebuild
02:02:45 Execute commands: Loading /private/var/folders/8n/b15fh_dj3ps6xm3lb0vh2ps00000gq/T/AppTranslocation/66A1867F-FF2B-438C-88EC-60DB52BA70A8/d/LiteIDE.app/Contents/Resources/litebuild/command
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/litebuild
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/golangast
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/welcome
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/rustedit
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/markdown
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/litetty
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/litedebug
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/jsonedit
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/gopresent
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/golangplay
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/golangpackage
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/golangfmt
02:02:45 GolangEdit: Not found guru, back to oracle!
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/golangedit
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/golangdoc
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/golangcode
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/gdbdebugger
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/filebrowser
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/fakevimedit
02:02:45 LiteApp: Loaded plugin/dlvdebugger
02:02:45 EnvManager: init load environment
02:02:45 LiteBuild: go environment changed
02:02:45 GolangDoc: found godoc at /usr/local/go/bin/godoc
02:02:45 GolangCode: go environment changed
02:02:45 GolangCode: Found gocode at /private/var/folders/8n/b15fh_dj3ps6xm3lb0vh2ps00000gq/T/AppTranslocation/66A1867F-FF2B-438C-88EC-60DB52BA70A8/d/LiteIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/gocode
02:02:45 HtmlWidgetFactory: QTextBrowser
02:02:45 DefaultHtmlWidgetFactory: QTextBrowser
02:02:45 LiteApp: Finished loading
02:03:23 DlvDebugger: dlv was not found on system PATH (hint: is Delve installed?)
02:03:23 LiteDebug: Failed to start debugger
```

when I run the dlv command from terminal it works fine:

```
bash-3.2$ dlv
Delve is a source level debugger for Go programs.

Delve enables you to interact ...
...
Use "dlv [command] --help" for more information about a command.
bash-3.2$ which dlv
/usr/local/bin/dlv
```

Looks like LiteIDE doesn't use standard PATH value. Any ideas how I can tell LiteIDE where the debugger is? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the code of LiteIDE found that it expects to have dlv in $GOPATH/bin, so it doesn't look to $PATH for searching the dlv.

So as I installed delve via brew, I just made a soft link and get the following error:

```
Program exited with code 1
/Users/me/go/bin/dlv exec "myapp" [/Users/me/go/src/myapp]
could not launch process: could not fork/exec
```

I presumed that probably delve should be installed and compiled manually, so did it, but it did not help. In an hour or so I found the solution eventually:

If you compile, sign and install delve yourself or install it via brew on OSX **BE SURE** you do

```
sudo pkill taskgated
```

What helped me and it makes dlv running even in LiteIDE eliminating the problem above.